# jquery - PHP-serialized String is cutted

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I have a form which I finally send via AJAX.
In that form I put some values as a PHP-serialized-string in a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="userData" id="userData" value="<?php echo serialize($userInput); ?>">
```

Now when I send this form..

```
let data = $('#step-4 :input').serialize();                     
$('#step-5').load('php/send.php?data='+data, function() { ...
```

the serialized string is somehow cutted..

> [userData] => a:13:{s:6:

and I can't figure out why(?)

Comment: please show ur jquery ajax code

Comment: What's the original data? What's the result of serialze? Is it truncated before your form is submitted, or after? Do you have some more code to show us?

Comment: `serialize()` data contains quotes, I would say that there is a `"` after `a:13:{s:6:` as `s:6` says a 6 char string is to follow, and that has terminated the HTML `value="` attribute at that point

Comment: Dont pass serialized data this way it wont work

Comment: @ RiggsFolly .. hmmm.. I guess that could be it :/ .. what would be a good approach to achieve this?

Comment: I would bet your months pay packet on it

Comment: So this is the HTML you are trying to pass back to the javascript AJAX call right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly .. yes

Comment: i think ur data is already serialized in ur input and ur again serializing in jquery

Comment: You had better show us a bit more of what you are trying to do. Currently I only have a view through the letter box and I cannot see enough to make any suggestions

Comment: `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(serialize($userInput)); ?>"`

Comment: My first suggestion would be to create one hidden input for each item you want to pass back. Then it would also make getting at each of these data items easier in JS as there is not `unserialize()` in js that will unserialize a PHP serialized string

Comment: All other and probably better suggestions would depend on seeing exactly what you are actually trying to do

Comment: @ RiggsFolly.. I have a form where the user makes some input .. after that the user has to fill out a second form (at this point I have the values of the first-form in a PHP $_REQUEST-variable).. with the second form, I want the input-data of the first form. to be send with

Comment: Then one hidden field per item of data is a recognised method of doing this, although instead I would also suggest putting the data from page1 in the session when you process form1 and then pick it up form there in form2. this would also be more secure as user cannot edit the page and amend the hidden fields if you use session

Comment: @RiggsFolly... thank you for the advice.. I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this should solve your query....

change your html...

```
<input type="text" name="userData" id="userData" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($userInput)); ?>">
```